# hive Error in semantic analysis Input format must implement InputFormat

Tags: hive

Im trying to use a custom InputFormat and it fails with the below error.

```
FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: 1:31 Input format must implement InputFormat. Error encountered near token..
```

looks like the reason that the below isn't working is because I'm using a newer version of the InputFormat API (import org.apache.hadoop.mapred which is the old versus import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce which is the new).

Here are my versions of both Hive and Hadoop.

```
adoop@domU-12-31-39-0B-21-24:~$ hadoop version
Hadoop 1.0.3

hadoop@domU-12-31-39-0B-21-24:~$ hive --version
Hive version 0.8.1.8
```

hadoop@domU-12-31-39-0B-21-24:~$

Hadoop 1.0.3 jars have the new APIs as well.. What am i missing ?
How do i enforce hive to use the newer version of the APIs?

Comment: @balaswamy-vaddeman, did you solve this? Or just change back to org.apache.hadoop.mapred?